# Adding app.config (Application Configuration File) in Visual Studio Professional 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, app-config

I can't get the Application Configuration File template to show up under my Add > New Item > Visual C#. I've run a repair. I've uninstalled and reinstalled. I've deleted and added Cache folders. I've run devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates. Nothing is working. 
If anyone can tell me specifically what installation elements I should be including, and specifically what type of Project I need to start that might help. 
I want to create a simple .Net Web Form in .Net and C# and need to include an app.config file.

Comment: A WebForms project will have a web.config, not app.config. Is that what you meant?

Comment: What is the project type?

Comment: The Web application project templates create the appropriate configuration files already: web.config for Full Framework, appsettings.json etc for ASP.NET Core. There's no need to add `app.config` by hand, nor will it work

Comment: ASP.Net Web Application

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project (depending on the type of project like a web application for example) it will automatically create a template app.config file.

Worst case just make a txt file in notepad and call it [Appname].config

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to go in the project properties, then the Settings tab. If there are no settings yet, a link should exist in the middle of the empty tab to create a default setting file. Add one Application or User setting and save. Among other things a config file will be created for you too.